# Zabbix Agent Active cannot establish TCP connection to Zabbix Server. No Route To Host

Tags: tcp, connection, agent, zabbix

Currently I'm using Zabbix to monitor one of my web servers on AWS and it has a public accessible IP address. All the passive checks work fine such as port status check, CPU usage check and etc. However, the active checks do not work.

From the log file of Zabbix Agent, it shows the error message as

```
103548:20160902:065121.022 active check configuration update from [118.189.77.114:10051] 
started to fail (cannot connect to [[118.189.77.114]:10051]: [113] No route to host)
```

I suspect the problem is that my Zabbix server is a local VM which only has a **private IP** address. The public IP is the one shared by all the hosts within the office network. Hence, when the agent tries to initiate the TCP connection, it could not reach Zabbix Server coz the connection was dropped at the router. Basically, it is like 
[image: what shown in the pic.]

Is anybody facing the same issue or have any idea how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Btw, I've enabled active checks, adding the public IP of my Zabbix Server to serverActive address and put the right Hostname in the conf file. I am using Zabbix Agent 3.2 and Zabbix Server 3.0

Answer (score 0):

While `118.189.77.114` is not a private IP, it can not be reached from AWS - probably because your provider does not allow that.

There isn't really anything you can do (except placing Zabbix server somewhere else) - you must have a way for the agent to connect to the server for the active items to work.